# how to group elements in a list based on frequency into a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to group the similar numbers into one tuple of the form (number,frequency).

```
l1=[2,2,2,5,5,7]
```

How do I convert this list into the list below

```
l1=[(2,3),(5,2),(7,1)]
```

Comment: [use a Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7]

l1 = Counter(l1).items()
```

The "key" is the list element, and the "value" is the occurrence count.

For example:

```
In [7]: from collections import Counter

In [8]: l1=[2,2,2,5,5,7]

In [9]: Counter(l1).keys()
Out[9]: [2, 5, 7]

In [10]: Counter(l1).values()
Out[10]: [3, 2, 1]

In [11]: zip(Counter(l1).keys(), Counter(l1).values())
Out[11]: [(2, 3), (5, 2), (7, 1)]

In [12]: Counter(l1).items()
Out[12]: [(2, 3), (5, 2), (7, 1)]
```

Comment: Counter(l1).items() is enough ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Counter` like so:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l1=[2,2,2,5,5,7]
>>> c = Counter(l1)
>>> c.items()
dict_items([(2, 3), (5, 2), (7, 1)])
```